# Android NDK: Read large file using AAssetManager

Tags: android, android-ndk, c++17

I am trying to read in a large file using asset manager in Android NDK.

The problem is that the code that I have written is not reading the entire content. Rather only a portion of it. When I try to achieve the same functionality using Java, it is giving me correct results.

This is the code that I have written:

```cpp
    std::string file = hats::files::SOURCE_DATASET_FILENAME;
    AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
    AAsset *asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, file.c_str(), AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
    size_t assetLength = AAsset_getLength(asset);
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(assetLength + 1);

    int nbytes{0};
    while( (nbytes = AAsset_read(asset, buffer, assetLength)) > 0) {
        LOGD("%s", buffer);
        AAsset_seek(asset, nbytes, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    AAsset_close(asset);
    return env->NewStringUTF(file.c_str());
```

I am not able to understand why only partial file is being read. I am not able to find any proper tutorial for Android NDK also.

Please help me out.

Comment: `LOGD("%s", buffer);` The buffer is not filled yet. You should only log the first `nbytes` of the buffer.

Comment: It should not be needed to use a seek() function.

Comment: You have a loop. Ok. But where are the next readed bytes written?

Comment: Please post working java code in a new code block.

Comment: `AAsset_read(asset, buffer, assetLength...)` This always puts the readed bytes at start of the buffer. But you should put them after the already readed bytes in the buffer.

Comment: `LOGD("%s", buffer);`  If it is a large -filled- buffer it will not print the whole buffer. How do you check that only a part is read?